# Why am I getting exception when trying to get each process cpu usage?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is what i did in the class Core:

```
public static int GetCpuUsage(string name)
        {
            var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total", name);
            cpuCounter.NextValue();
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return (int)cpuCounter.NextValue();
        }
```

I marked not to use the line: //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
For some reason if i use this line the whoe method is working very very very slow.
Once i removed this line it's working fast but all the processes i see or 0% cpu usage or 100%.

This is how i use it in Form1:

```
void PopulateApplications()
        {
            DoubleBufferedd(dataGridView1, true);


                int rcount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
                int rcurIndex = 0;
                foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
                {

                        try
                        {
                            if (File.Exists(p.MainModule.FileName))
                            {

                                cpuusage = Core.GetCpuUsage(p.MachineName);

                                        var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                                        Image ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                                        ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
                                        ima = (Image)(new Bitmap(ima, new Size(25, 25)));
                                        String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
                                        if (rcurIndex < rcount - 1)
                                        {
                                            var currentRow = dataGridView1.Rows[rcurIndex];
                                            //currentRow.Cells[0].Value = false;  
                                            currentRow.Cells[0].Value = ima;
                                            currentRow.Cells[1].Value = p.ProcessName;
                                            currentRow.Cells[2].Value = cpuusage;
                                            currentRow.Cells[3].Value = status;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(
                                                ima, p.ProcessName, cpuusage, status);
                                        }
                                        rcurIndex++;
                            }
                        }
                        catch ( Exception e)
                        {
                            string t = "error";
                        }
                }       

                // if the previout rowscount > current then remove the other rows
                if (rcurIndex < rcount - 1)
                {
                    for (int i = rcurIndex; i < rcount - 1; i++)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rcurIndex);
                    }
                }
        }
```

This is the results of the cpu usage:

[image]

Comment: Updated my question changed the machine name but now im getting another exception about the category.

Comment: Edited my question with the code i changed and using now but now im getting access denied exception. How can i solve it ? Im using try and catch in form1 but yet it stop on the access denied.

Comment: Regarding "Access denied": Read the notes regarding privileges in the *Remarks* section of the [MSDN documentation about PerformanceCounter(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9ffskxdc)

Comment: Does your code still complain with "Access Denied" when you run it with Administrator privileges? (Make sure by executing it via Explorer context menu "Run as administrator...")

Comment: elgonzo look at my question now this is the latest code im trying now. The method in Form1 PopulateApplications() i call it from a timer tick event every 5 seconds so maybe i don't need the line: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); in the GetCpuUsage method. Using this line making it all working very very very slow it at all.  Second thing maybe i dont need to read all the access denied processes since they are system processes ? So i dont mind about it.

Comment: elgonzo without this line System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);  it's working fast i see the processes i wanted to see in the dataGridView1 those are access denied the try and catch will handle. The problem now is that all the processes show 0% cpu usage or 100% cpu usage not sure why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55289/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-user3681442).

Comment: elgonzo i added to my question a screenshot of what im getting now. Some processes show 100% some 0% maybe it's because the access denied problem ? If this is the problem maybe i can somehow bypass those system access denied process and not list/read them. And if this is not the problem what could it be ?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", name);
```

Here's what I use to get the CPU usage of a single process (devenv on this case)

```
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.ProcessName == "devenv")) {
            using (PerformanceCounter pcProcess = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", process.ProcessName))
            {
                pcProcess.NextValue();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                return pcProcess.NextValue();
            }
        }
```

You can easily change it to retrieve the cpu of every process by removing the Where clause. Keep in mind it'll take forever to finish if there are a lot of processes.

Comment: Marcelo and how do i use this now this method with what i have in form1 the foreach and the process list ? Before the change i used string name and p.MachineName now after the change how do i use this method with each process ?

Comment: Marcelo please look at my question i edited it after changed it according to your answer. ( Did you try it on one process or all the running processes ? )

Comment: Marcelo your solution is working for me too but it's working for one process. I need it to get the cpu usage for all the running processes.

Comment: @user3681442 DIdn't see you wanted it for EVERY process. Edited my answer to something correct now.